# Change value on type=submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a very easy topic, but I don't seem to make any solution on Google work. I am working on a hack-around for a form. I can't add id's or classes. All i have is `type=submit`. What is the easiest solution to change the text on the button?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $input = document.find("input[type=submit]");
    $input.val('OLOLOLOL');
});
```

**OR**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(':submit').val('OLOLOLOL');
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

They don't change anything. Is it syntax or something worse? Plain javascript can work too

Comment: I use $ to mark it as jquery

Comment: dude your 2nd code works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kBkM/)

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `input[type=submit]` selector for the search as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9q7M/):

```
$("input[type=submit]").val("New value");
```

As far as I know, jQuery uses the same selectors as CSS does (and many [others](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/))!

Comment: more like jquery works with css selectors… jQuery has many extra selectors that css doesn't have….

Comment: I know that. But you can basically use CSS selectors!

Answer (score 2):

i would try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $input = $(document).find("input[type=submit]");
    $input.val('OLOLOLOL');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $input = $(document).find("input[type=submit]");
    $input.val('OLOLOLOL');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First one works only for input type button but second one works for both input type button as well as button type submit.

So, choice is yours if you want to bind the function anyway if the type is button choose second option.

But I just saw your edited question and would do like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').val("Your Value");
```

Comment: @Victor No, I didn't see your answer.